# All the Content of the html has moved to left in mobile view

Tags: html, css

Check the below image
[image]

I'm new to web development 
https://gunhawk008.github.io/tenWebsite/index.html //This is the hosted website

https://github.com/gunhawk008/tenWebsite //Code of the website

Comment: Post your code please

Comment: Can you share the code snippet. That will be more of help to answer this question

Comment: https://github.com/gunhawk008/tenWebsite

Comment: Did you try Overflow-x:hidden; ?

Comment: Yes! Not Working

Comment: Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Ok, please host it on github pages.We can provide better help to a running site.Go to settings>scroll down to Github Pages>Click none>Select Master Branch

Comment: https://gunhawk008.github.io/tenWebsite/index.html

Comment: You should edit post and add code... and say what is you need . please read help center

Comment: Consider adding an [MCVE] to make it as easy as possible for us to help you. By providing just enough code to replicate the problem you may even find the issue yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have seen that the black blank space is appearing only in mobile view.Please add this css:

```
@media all and (max-width:991px){
body{
   overflow-x:hidden;
}

}
```

After applying the above code, please clear the browser cache to see the change.

Answer (score 0):

Delete your body text-align left and it will fix your problem

Comment: Hey! Thank you Reaching Out! I tried by removing the css text-align left but its still the same!